# Client Side function returning HTML Code instead of Server Side return value

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, client-side, server-side

The alert(result) within the success JavaScript Function is showing a dialog box that is only the entire HTML code of the page. It is bizarre. I cannot get the client side to call the server side function in C#.

It is meant to print the string given in the server side function.

**submit.aspx**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function GetName() {

            PageMethods.Name(Success, Failure);
        }
        function Success(result) {
            alert(result);
        }
        function Failure(error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID='ScriptManager1' runat='server' EnablePageMethods='true' />
    <div>  
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Get Name" OnClientClick='GetName();return false;' />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**submit.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;

using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using PdfSharp;
using PdfSharp.Drawing;
using PdfSharp.Drawing.Layout;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

using System.Runtime.Serialization;

//needed for SQL access
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections;

using System.Net;
using PDFCreator;

namespace theform
{ 


    public partial class submit : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //functions fun = new functions();
            //fun.Main();
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static string Name()
        {
            string Name = "Hello Rohatash Kumar";
            return Name;
        }
        //        <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="create_array();" />
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you might be leaving something out, I tried your code and it works fine.

Comment: Is there some option in Visual Studio, or perhaps the Server that needs to be enabled?

Answer (score 0):

can you use onclick button event to show alert.this is another method

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Insert is successfull')", true);
```